# Async/await, "unresolved variable or type await"

Tags: javascript, async-await, webstorm

```
    let usersInAuth0 = [];    
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      const usersInAuth0InPage = await getUsersFromAuth0(i); // error in WebStorm
      if (_.isEmpty(usersInAuth0InPage)){
        return res.status(200).send(usersInAuth0);
      } else {
        usersInAuth0.push(usersInAuth0InPage);
      }
    }

    const getUsersFromAuth0 = async (page) => {
      return await management.getUsers({per_page:100, page: page})
    }
```

Trying to use async/await. From the auth0 management API you can only get 100 user per page so I'm making several request until I have all users.

WebStorm gives the warning (on line 3): "unresolved variable or type await".

How am I suppose to use async/await in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use `await`, the function it's inside needs to be `async`. For example:

```
(async () => {
  let usersInAuth0 = [];    
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const usersInAuth0InPage = await getUsersFromAuth0(i); // error in webstorm
    if (_.isEmpty(usersInAuth0InPage)){
      return res.status(200).send(usersInAuth0);
    } else {
      usersInAuth0.push(usersInAuth0InPage);
    }
  }

  const getUsersFromAuth0 = page => management.getUsers({per_page:100, page: page});
})();
```

https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/unresolved-variable-type-await/

Note that since `management.getUsers` returns a Promise, you don't need to make `getUsersFromAuth0` async - just return the promise and `await` its resolution higher up.

Because `async` functions return promises, you'll need to make sure that whatever *consumes* this whole code block is able to handle the its return value being a promise. (your `return res.status(200).send(usersInAuth0);` won't actually return that value - the function will return a promise that *resolves* to that value, should the conditional it's inside be fulfilled)

Comment: `Parsing error, Unexpected token =>` is the error I get when I copy and paste this directly

Comment: Sounds like you're using an ancient browser that doesn't support arrow functions. Ideally, use Babel in your build process to automatically translate ES6+ syntax (such as arrow functions) into ES5 syntax. This lets you write in the latest and greatest version of the language while also allowing obsolete browsers to understand your scripts.